# Silverlight 4 and Page.Resources Binding

Tags: silverlight, binding, resources

In my SL4 application, I have a Class called Images which has two properties (ImagePath, ImageName) and a method getImages() which retruns ObservableCollection list of all Images.
I need to create a Resource on my Page so that when a DataTemplate is loaded dynamically it can have access to the Images in one of its ComboBox field.

How can I do that?

```
<Page.Resources>
<local:Images x:Key="MyImages"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

But in my code behind file I cannot access the MyImages

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Comment: Please detail the term "DataTemplate is loaded dynamically"?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

**1. Use global app resource file.**

> ```
>  <Application.Resources>
>         <ResourceDictionary>
>             <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>                 <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/StylesA.xaml"/>
>                 <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/StylesB.xaml" />
>             </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>         </ResourceDictionary>
>     </Application.Resources>
> ```

And within StylesA.xaml just put style you have to use

> ```
>   <StackPanel>
>             <StackPanel.Resources>
>                 <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
>                     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
>                     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
>                 </Style>
>             </StackPanel.Resources>            
>             <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"></TextBlock> ....
> ```

**2. Use local control Resources section.**

> ```
>   <StackPanel>
>             <StackPanel.Resources>
>                 <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
>                     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
>                     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
>                 </Style>
>             </StackPanel.Resources>            
>             <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"></TextBlock> ....
> ```

**3. Just use** `Page.Resources` **within your page**

> ```
>  <navigation:Page.Resources>
>         <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
>             <Setter Property="Control.Template">
>                 <Setter.Value>
>                     <ControlTemplate>
>                         <Border>
>                             <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#60000000" StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
>                         </Border>
>                     </ControlTemplate>
>                 </Setter.Value>
>             </Setter>
>         </Style>      
>     </navigation:Page.Resources>
> ```

I hope it will help. :)